# Linear electrical network

Tags: output, linear, network

Is zero input zero output test of an electrical network is necessary and sufficient condition for network to be linear i.e for example if  I have electrical network of N-port and I measure current and voltages across all the N-ports without applying any external input and got zero output at all the N-ports,  so now  is it sufficient to assume that this network is linear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is zero input zero output test of an electrical network is necessary and sufficient condition for network to be linear

No. It is necessary but not sufficient.

Here's a simple circuit that passes this test but isn't linear:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8Z9pt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>